# Anchor dropdown menu for options with hidden content

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, anchor

I have a drop down menu that I would like to add anchors to. The drop down has 4 options which are all hidden on start. When an option is clicked, that section will be visible. The drop down menu will have content above it and I need the page to move down when an option is clicked and becomes visible. How do I add anchors to these options?

I'm not well versed in javascript, but this is what I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
                    if ( this.value == '0'){
                        $("#value0").show();
                    } else {
                        $("#value0").hide();
                    }

                    if ( this.value == '1'){
                        $("#value1").show();
                    } else {
                        $("#value1").hide();
                    }

                    if ( this.value == '2'){
                        $("#value2").show();
                    } else {
                        $("#value2").hide();
                    }

                    if ( this.value == '3'){
                        $("#value3").show();
                    } else {
                        $("#value3").hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!--Drop Down-->
    <p><select id="purpose">
    <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="1">1 column w/big hero</option>
    <option value="2">1 column w/s-curve</option>
    <option value="3">1 column; linear</option>
    </select></p>
    <!--End Drop Down-->

    <table width="100%" height="1000" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>  

    <!--Default Value 0-->
    <div id="value0" style="display:block;"></div>
    <!--End Default Value 0--> 

    <!--Option 1-->
    <div align="center" id="value1" style="display:none;">Content for value 1</div>
    <!--End Option 1-->  

    <!--Option 2-->
    <div align="center" id="value2" style="display:none;">Content for value 2</div>
    <!--End Option 2--> 

    <!--Option 3-->
    <div align="center" id="value3" style="display:none;">Content for Value 3</div>
    <!--End Option 3-->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice to see that you are starting with Javascript, welcome! I've updated your question a bit (and gave you an answer) to make the code more readable. Happy coding...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it's much more readable. Unfortunately, after inserting the answer you gave me I didn't get any movement. I added it to value 1 with no such luck. I have it demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/bz4140aq/3/

I also used it in my original working document with no such luck. Is there anything that I inserted incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the top level of the item your fetching.

```
var valueTop = $("#value0").offset().top; // what is the offset of the item
$(window).scrollTop( valueTop ); // set the window's scroll position
```

In your example:

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function() {
    if ( this.value == '0'){
        $(value0).show();
        var vtop = $("#value0");
        var valueTop = vtop.offset().top
        $(window).scrollTop( valueTop );    
    } else {
        $("#value0").hide();
    }
})
```

You can also animate the scrolling:

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function() {
    if ( this.value == '0'){
        $(value0).show();
        var vtop = $("#value0");
        var valueTop = vtop.offset().top
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: valueTop},500);
    } else {
        $("#value0").hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the submission, I inserted your code and wasn't able to get it working until I played around with it. I posted my answer for what worked below.

Comment: Not sure of you still need help? If so, please share. Was the answer helpful? Please accept it if so :-)

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it working eventually. I ran into an issue where after pasting your code my content wasn't showing up. I then changed this: vtop.show(); 
to this: $(value0).show();
And now everything works perfectly! Thank you again for the help!

Comment: No problem, you would do me an awesome favour by selecting the green checkmark next to my answer :-)